# Sharepoint Migration on premisses to online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

Is there a way to migrate a SharePoint site, including document library, site collection, and everything else, finally the entire content of an On Premises environment for the SharePoint Online environment using only PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However going by the fact your asking I assume you don't know a lot of Powershell. In which case it will take lots of learning. Alternatively I recommend buying a third party utility to perform this function. Plenty available. Will save you a large amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Powershell to migrate SP Onprem to SP Online. Please refer to below article for detailed information:

https://migrationspo.blogspot.com/2016/06/sharepoint-migration-to-online-spo-o365_20.html

There are ways to migrate the site collection from a On Premises environment to a SharePoint Online environment. However, I do not think Powershell is the best way.

I suggest you use a third tool. Using Powershell, the amount of time and effort involved will normally cost a client far more than a third party tool. Especially if you have a customized UI in On Premises environment.